# Does integral by parts apply when the integrand is discontinuous at some point?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we have: $H(x)=a (x\ge0); H(x)=0 (x<0)$, where $a>0$ is a constant. Define $K(x)=ax (x\ge0); K(x)=0(x<0)$.

When evaluate the integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} H(x) f(x) dx
$$

where $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable.

Does the above integral equal to the following expression?

$$
-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} K(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx} dx + f(x)K(x)|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
$$

If not, please give me the reasons and a particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $[-C,C]$, apply integration by parts on $[-C,0]$ and $[0,C]$ respectively (both functions are continuous and differentiable here, so you're allowed to use the ordinary results).
Then, $\int_{-C}^C H(x)f(x)\textrm{d}x=-\int_{-C}^0 K(x)f'(x)\textrm{d}x+[K(x)f(x)]_{-C}^0-\int_0^C K(x)f'(x)\textrm{d}x+[K(x)f(x)]_0^C.$ Now, analysing this bit, you see that we are done if we are allowed to say that $[K(x)f(x)]^0_{-C}+[K(x)f(x)]_{0}^C=[K(x)f(x)]_{-C}^C$ and this holds, since $K$ is continuous.

The situation becomes more tricky when you're trying to fit the result on a function, the anti-derivative of which is not continuous. If the anti-derivative is bounded and $f(0)=0,$ then the result still works (just check the proof above).

Comment: what is anti-derivative?

Comment: $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$ if $F'=f$ or, more generally, $F(x)=C+\int_{x_0}^x f(t)\textrm{d}t$ for some appropriate $C,x_0\in \mathbb{R}$.